# How to compare Rails models from app vs plugins/gems models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins

I have the following problem: 
I have a running rails application and I want to install a plugin, but this plugin comes with a lot of functionality (and models) which is already in my rails application. So the first step for me is to check if the models from the plugin are existing and if they are I want to know which are the different attributes for generating migration files.

Is there some code I can use?

Answer (score 0):

Plugins and gems should always but ALWAYS use namespaces when providing additional models and sql tables to an application to avoid name clashes. If that isn't the case, advise the owner to do so asap. You  should not have to go through the tedious task of comparing the two.

Can you tell us which plugin you're talking about? Best and easiest would be to open the source code.

Comment: the plugin is called [communityengine](https://github.com/bborn/communityengine) and there are some problems -> they copie their migration files into the Rails.root path without checking, if the table/model already exists

Comment: That wouldn't be so much of a problem if they had namespaced everything, but they didn't. Also, they mount their engine on '/'. Basically, you should start your application with them, integrating it is a hassle. To be honest, I wouldn't even bother trying it out.

Comment: Thanks so far, at least I don't think that I do something wrong here. But I need this functionality so I have to integrate this piece of code. -.-

Comment: Here's the list of models they use. https://github.com/bborn/communityengine/tree/master/app/models have fun. Otherwise i know of a visual tool that generates a class digram of your schema file but i doubt it will help you here.

Comment: Thanks, but I did this already ;) and railrody brings no solution for my problem.